# How do you extract a whole word containing substring?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

If I have a file that looks like this:

```
example.png example.jpg example2.jpg example2.png example.swf
example2.swf example3.jpg example4.jpg example3.png example3.swf
```

and I want to extract the words containing swf for example, the output would look something like this

```
example.swf 
example2.swf
example3.swf
```

I tried `grep -o "swf[^[:space:]]*"`, which just prints a bunch of `swf`, and then I tried `grep -o '[^ ]*a\.swf[^ ]*'`, which output very few *lines* containing "swf". Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: You're close I think - but don't you want `grep -o '[^[:space:]]*swf'` i.e. zero or more non-space  characters *before* the `swf` substring?

Comment: @steeldriver Why didn't you write that as an answer? You'd have received my upvote.

Answer (score 10):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -o '\b\w*\.swf\b' file
```

Output:

```
example.swf
example2.swf
example3.swf
```

---

> `\b`: a zero-width word boundary
>
> `\w`: word character
>
> `\.`: match one dot

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
grep -o '[^ ]*\.swf' file.txt
```

- `[^ ]*` matches zero or more non-space characters
- `\.swf` matches literal `.swf`

**Example:**

```
% grep -o '[^ ]*\.swf' file.txt
example.swf
example2.swf
example3.swf
```

Answer (score 4):

**First step**

Replace spaces with line ends using `sed`

**Second step**

Filter the output using `grep`

**Example**

`sed -e s/\ /\\n/g file | grep .swf`

Comment: simple and easy. good approach.